# How to use premake on *.lua files

Tags: lua, premake

How do I use `premake4`? I have a `.lua` file that I want to compile.

I downloaded the executable `premake4` but when I run `./premake4 myfile` it gives me an error.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile"? Lua scripts are generally interpreted, rather than compiled.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, Premake4 expects to execute a script called `premake4.lua`. You are strongly advised to hold to this convention.

However, if you absolutely must use a different file, you can call `premake4 --file=<insert file here>`. But again, you are advised to just use standard Premake conventions.

Note that this is all spelled out in Premake's documentation. Even the command-line help will tell you how to use the `--file` switch.